# Change <input> onfocus value using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I expect to see `Bond-Patterson` after focus input field, but the result is `Bond`. What's wrong and how can I do this?

```js
$('input[name="surname"]').attr("onfocus", "this.placeholder='Bond-Patterson'");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Click here" onfocus="this.placeholder='Bond'" />
```

Comment: That isn't how the `onfocus` attribute works. Are you trying to set the value of the field to `Bond-Patterson`?

Comment: a need to do this when HTML loaded. A simplified code was shown

Comment: It actually (surprisingly) works with `attr("onfocus", "this.placeholder='Bond-Patterson'");` but that's definetly not the way it's supposed to be done. (Note: `onfocus` value should be javascript code, of course)

Comment: you are violating the rules of onfocus event

Comment: @tahan need to do what, though? It's not clear what you're attempting to achieve. Do you want to set a value when the element is focused, or change the placeholder? Either case is a little odd, really.

Answer (score 0):

That's work as need, when I run as Stackoverflow code snippet.

I found, that problem was in old Jquery version. It was `Jquery 1.5.1`

Last Jquery works fine. Thank you

Comment: If that was the problem I'd suggest deleting the question is it was very vague, and this answer is unlikely to be relevant to anyone else.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you see the [w3schools documentation on onfocus event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocus.asp)

```js
$('input[name="surname"]').on('focus', function() {
  $('input[name="surname"]').attr("placeholder", "Bond-Patterson");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Click here" />
```

Answer (score -1):

There is an issue with attributes priority.

**Note**: Tag attributes have precedence somehow.

You can directly write:

```
<input type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Click here" onfocus="this.placehoder='Bond-Peterson'"/>
```

But this changes/updates the placeholder value whenever you click or focus on the input.

```js
$('input[name="surname"]').focus(() => {
  console.log("focus");
  $('input[name="surname"]').attr("placeholder", "Bond-son");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Click here"/>
```

I am not sure what are you trying to do. But if I guess correctly, you want something like this: 
When a user focuses on the input, it shows a different value for placeholder and when he focuses out it should show another one.

Working example

```js
$('input[name="surname"]').focus(() => {
      $('input[name="surname"]').attr("placeholder", "Bond-Petterson");
    })
    
    
    $('input[name="surname"]').focusout(() => {
      $('input[name="surname"]').attr("placeholder", "Bond");
    })
```

```html
    

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Click here"/>
```